# Addition and multiplication of integers

Tags: analysis, integers, number-systems

Reading the book Analysis I (Fourth Edition), by Terence Tao, I found, on page 78, Lemma 4.1.3 (Addition and multiplication are well-defined.)

The Lemma says:

Let a, b, a', b', c, d natural numbers. If (a — b) = (a' — b'), then (a — b) + (c — d) = (a' — b') + (c — d) and
(a — b) x (c — d) = (a' — b') x (c — d),
and also (c — d) + (a — b) = (c — d) + (a' — b')
and (c — d ) x (a — b) = (c — d) x (a' — b'). Thus addition and multiplication are well-defined operations (equal inputs give equal outputs).

Next, the author presents a Proof.

Well... my question is whether the Lemma should also include, in the hypothesis, (c — d) = (c' — d'), with c' and d' being natural numbers.

Note: The definition of an integer is given, in the mentioned book, in 4.1.1:

An integer is an expression of the form a — b, where a and b are natural numbers. Two integers are considered to be equal,
a — b = c — d, if and only if a + d = c + b.

Comment: Lemma doesn't need c'/d'. Looks like he's establishing well definedness of arithmetic on the integers using $a'/b'$ alone ultimately to establish the $a$ and $b$ don't matter, just their difference. Proving that assertion would be more complicated if $c'/d'$ were introduced and would largely be redundant.